# Zend Framework - Updating int field to NULL updates to 0 instead of NULL

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a field that is int and I am updating the field to NULL. 
Here is the code I used-

```
    $db = $Table->getAdapter();
    $db->beginTransaction();

    try {
        $db->update('table_name', array('is_approved' => NULL), array('id = ?' => $id));
        $document_db->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $document_db->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
```

When I looked at the field, it shows 0 instead of null. I read many of the related questions here at stackoverflow. One says to use strict mode. How to enable strict mode using Zend.

Any other workaround? I need to update to NULL
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $db = $Table->getAdapter();
    $db->beginTransaction();

    try {
        $null = new Zend_Db_Expr("NULL");
        $db->update('table_name', array('is_approved' => $null), array('id = ?' => $id));
        $document_db->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $document_db->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set it using that way: `new Zend_Db_Expr('NULL')`